# mariabackup of database running in docker

Tags: mariadb, backup, xtrabackup

I have MariaDB running in a Docker container with the container's data directory `/var/lib/mysql/` mapped to the host directory `/mnt/data/`.

I want to run `mariabackup` from the host to create a physical backup of the data directory (which is `/mnt/data` as far as the host is concerned and `/var/lib/mysql/` from the container's perspective).

I get an error, however, running `mariabackup` that says it cannot find the data directory:

```
$ mariabackup --backup --user=backup --stream=xbstream -h /mnt/data/ | gzip > foo.gz
Connecting to MySQL server host: 127.0.0.1, user: backup, password: set, port: 3306 ...
Using server version 10.3.10-MariaDB-1:10.3.10+maria~bionic
Warning: MySQL variable 'datadir' points to nonexistent directory '/var/lib/mysql/'
Warning: option 'datadir' has different balues:
    '/mnt/data/' in defaults file
    '/var/lib/mysql/' in SHOW VARIABLES
mariabackup based on MariaDB server 10.1.29-MariaDB debian-linux-gnu (x86_54)
mariabackup: uses posix_fadvise().
mariabackup: Can't change dir to '/var/lib/mysql/ (Errcode: 2 "No such file or directory")
mariabackup: cannot my_setwd /var/lib/mysql/
```

Something similar happens when I don't specify the data directory with the `-h` flag. I expected `mariabackup` to `cd` to `/mnt/data/`, execute the commands it needs to run on the server, and everything to simply work because it doesn't seem like it should matter what `SHOW VARIABLES` says if there's a valid data directory at `/mnt/data/`.

- I understand the warning that `mariabackup` sees two different paths for `datadir`, one that I provided via `-h` and another on the server.
- Why, however, does `mariabackup` try using `/var/lib/mysql/` when I explicity said (via the `-h` flag) that the data directory is `/mnt/data/`? Can I get `mariabackup` to ignore what the server says and `cd` to the directory I provided?
- If my approach is all wrong, what's the best way to do physical backups of a server running in a container with data directory mapped to a host directory?

Answer (score 2):

Create a symlink on your host so that Mariabackup thinks `/var/lib/mysql` exists. Then delete the symlink once you're done.

```
$ sudo ln -s /mnt/data /var/lib/mysql
```